# jQuery is not resizing images or playing them in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

So I have this jquery:

```
$(function () {
    //make the div take up the space given
    $('div#slideshow').width(100%);
    //make each slide fit within that div easily
    //I would prefer this be done by running through the slideshows div children,
    //rather than having to give each image the class of "slide", but I've had even worse luck with that
    $('.slide').each(function(index){
                $(this).width(90%);
        })
    //hide the first image
    $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        //put each slide up for six seconds and cause it to fade out while the
        //new one fades in over a period of two seconds
        $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeTo(2000, 0)
            .next('img').fadeTo(2000, 1).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 6000);
});
```

with this HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img style='position:relative;' width="400px" src="https://consumermediallc.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/totinos-stock-08-2014.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/66fa7962b68e90da541078fcc9efdc25/tumblr_inline_nnby3oQs8s1si7eaa_500.jpg" alt="Lightning Ghost" class="slide" />
    <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr02/14/7/enhanced-3829-1400068353-2.jpg" alt="Girraffe-dog" class="slide" />
    <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2291250-terrible-grimace-men-with-shovel.jpg" alt="Purpleish Kitty" class="slide" />
</div><!--slideshow-->
```

I'd say my comments in my jquery describe the trouble I'm having pretty well, when my code was just this:

```
$(function () {
        //hide the first image
        $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function () {
            //put each slide up for six seconds and cause it to fade out while the
            //new one fades in over a period of two seconds
            $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeTo(2000, 0)
                .next('img').fadeTo(2000, 1).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
        }, 6000);
    });
```

It worked fine, but I also had to set up the div and the images it contained specifically for that code, the goal here is to make this code for a slideshow a bit more flexible. By the way, here's the JSFiddle I've been trying to get this to work on: http://jsfiddle.net/75wczrw7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error – wrap width percents in brackets like this in both width calls:

```
$('div#slideshow').width('100%');
...
$(this).width('90%');
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I would loop through the images by referencing them as children of their parent div?

Comment: If you want to get an infinite loop and don't want to dramatically change your code you might simply detach the first image after fade out and append it to the parent. (https://api.jquery.com/detach/ – check this method)

Comment: What difference would detaching the image then instantly appending it to its same div make?

Comment: In this case your first image will become last - so you will be able to infinitely hide the first pic and show the second. Maybe we're talking about different things though?)

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem of the image that's fading in blocking out the fade out of the other image. I want the images to fade together and on top of each other, but I don't want to have to use the `position:absolute` property because it separates the slideshow from the webpage. I don't like having to reposition the slideshow _every_ time I change something on my webpage.

Comment: It seems to be a bit out of scope of your initial question but still: I don't think you will solve it without position: absolute, because it's the needed property to put one layer above another. You can wrap your slideshow in a div with position: static and set it's height explicitly on image change.

Answer (score 1):

Right now in your code the images keep on taking up new space unless all of them have loaded at least once. One more change you may need to make here is to give #slideshow a position : relative and .slide position:absolute.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's what I had to do in CSS which I found a bit frustrating. I guess I just forgot to do that with jQuery. I'm _really_ bad at jQuery.